# Memory increases/leaks in Core Graphics iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I have an UIViewController with a custom UIView in it. This custom UIView draws a pdf using `drawRect` and CoreGraphics. The UIViewController (pdfViewController) gets loaded multiple times:

```c
[self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:[[pdfViewController alloc] initWithPDF:pdfs[indexPath.row] uiColor:[self colorWithRGB:colors[indexPath.row][0]]]];
```

The custom UIView looks like this:

```c
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
    [super drawRect:rect];

     NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
     NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:PDF]];

     // Get GraphicsContext
     CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        // Open PDF Document
        CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument =  CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);
        CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocument, Page);

            // Get PDF Dimensions
            CGRect cropRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage, kCGPDFCropBox);

            // Set white background
            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 1.0);
            CGContextFillRect(ctx, rect);

            // Flip Coordinates and reset Origin
            CGContextGetCTM(ctx);
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -rect.size.height);

            // Set render quality
            CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);

            // Scale Matrix
            CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, rect.size.height/cropRect.size.height,rect.size.height/cropRect.size.height);
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -cropRect.origin.x, -cropRect.origin.y);

            // Draw PDF
            CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pdfPage);

        CGPDFPageRelease(pdfPage);
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);

}
```

The Memory doesnt get freed and each time the UIView is loaded with the UIViewController memory increases by ca. 6MB :/

Here is an image of the memory usage: [image]

Any help would be really appreciated, feel free to ask for more information

**UPDATE:**
The UIViews manual Memory Management in `drawRect` is perfectly fine. The UIView itself didn't release itself because of a (strong) delegate reference. Thanks again for all answers

Comment: Well, duh? you commented out releasing the resources: `//CGContextRelease(ctx);`. What's the idea behind that?

Comment: Uncommenting this line throws a warning and the app crashes: CGContextResetState: invalid context 0x10953d010. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: The problem for calling CGContextRelease() is you didn't create it.  It is just the already existing context into which the system intends you to draw.

Comment: So how can I completely unload the memory to avoid the memory leaks?

Comment: Is this under ARC or manual memory management?

Comment: Best starting point, whichever thing is holding the results of CA::Render::Shmem::new_shmem(unsigned long)

Comment: Everything is under ARC

Comment: Are you sure your view is being released?  Does it stop if you set a breakpoint in dealloc?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot Walt, I found the issue. The dealloc method wasn't invoked because the uiview was a (strong) delegate. Thanks a lot for your help and time. I wasn't pointing this out for hours...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the UIView itself is not being released. (Might as well fill out the answer now that we figured it out in the comments.)